# Inserting images in multiple posts native gallery

Tags: theme-development, images, dashboard

I am trying to find a solution to a problem that Wordpress seems to lack.

Here is a scenario:

I have uploaded images to a post using the native gallery to display the images. These images then appear under the gallery tab within the upload/insert and they will appear on the post. Works perfectly.

Further down the line I create a new post, I want to include images from my Media Library into the gallery without re-uploading the same images again.

I expected to find, "Insert into gallery", next to "Insert into post", but there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this.

Is there a solution to this? I have done a lot of theme development in the past, but amazed at there isn't a simple solution to this problem.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachments are a type of post, and a post can only have a single parent, that's why it's not natively possible to have an attachment associated with multiple posts- there is no mechanism for many-to-many associations. There are several ways to solve this, but how simple it is depends on your skill level or willingness to depend on plugins.

For plugins, there's [File Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/file-gallery/), and [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com), probably others. Otherwise a couple of custom solutions would be to use post meta data to store references to attachments for a post, and/or a taxonomy to "tag" images for each unique gallery you want them associated with along with some meta data for ordering them.

[Here is a thread](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Attaching-photos-to-multiple-posts-td709.html) on WordPress Hackers with an explanation from the lead developer and some possible solutions.